# My custom User Model is showing "Integrity Error - Foreign Key Constraint Failed" error

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have been trying to create a 'User' model that will take some fields. So, I have added these fields and modified the User model like that shown below:

```
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


# Create your models here.
class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, name, email, is_analyst ,DOB, gender, city_code, password=None, password2=None):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email, date of
        birth and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

        user = self.model(
            name=name,
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            is_analyst = is_analyst,
            DOB = DOB,
            gender = gender,
            city_code = city_code
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, name, email, is_analyst, DOB, gender, city_code, password=None):
        """
        Creates and saves a superuser with the given email, date of
        birth and password.
        """
        user = self.create_user(
            name=name,
            email=email,
            is_analyst = is_analyst,
            DOB = DOB,
            gender = gender,
            city_code = city_code,
            password=password,
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class User(AbstractUser):
    username = ''
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='Email',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )
    is_analyst = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    DOB = models.DateField()
    gender_choices = (
            ('M', 'Male'),
            ('F', 'Female')
        )
    
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=gender_choices)
    city_code = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    
    first_name = None
    last_name = None
    
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'    
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name', 'is_analyst', 'DOB', 'gender', 'city_code']    
    objects = MyUserManager()   
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(    
        'auth.Group',
        verbose_name='groups',
        blank=True,
        help_text='The groups this user belongs to. A user will get all permissions granted to each of their groups.',
        related_name='myuser_set' # Added related_name here
    )
    user_permissions = models.ManyToManyField(
        'auth.Permission',
        verbose_name='user permissions',
        blank=True,
        help_text='Specific permissions for this user.',
        related_name='myuser_set' # Added related_name here
    )

    def __str__(self):  
        return self.email   

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None): 
        "Does the user have a specific permission?" 
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always 
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        "Is the user a member of staff?"
        # Simplest possible answer: All admins are staff
        return self.is_admin


class OTP(models.Model):
    task_choice = [
        ('active', 'Active Account'),
        ('reset', 'Reset Pass'),
    ]
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    has_used = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    task_type = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=task_choice, default='active')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.code
```

In the above code you can also see the OTP model. It's working fine for the APIs. But when I'm login in the admin module and trying to delete any Otp model row or User row, It's showing me this error.

[image]

Also, when I have created the product app and written the models there. I can't add any products. The product app models are shown below:

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class Product(models.Model): 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    product_cat = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    product_cat_code = models.IntegerField()
    product_subcat = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    product_subcat_code = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.FloatField() 
    # digital = models.BooleanField(default=False, null = True, blank = True) 
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True) 
    def __str__(self) -> str: 
        return self.name 
    
    @property 
    def imageUrl(self): 
        try: 
            url = self.image.url 
        except: 
            url = "" 
        return url 

class Order(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True) 
    date_ordered = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) 
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)   
    transaction_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True) 

    @property
    def shipping(self):
        shipping = False
        order_items = self.orderitem_set.all()
        for i in order_items:
            if i.product.digital==False:
                shipping = True
        return shipping 

    @property
    def get_cart_total(self):
        order_items = self.orderitem_set.all()
        total = sum([item.get_total for item in order_items]) 
        return total

    @property
    def get_cart_items(self):
        order_items = self.orderitem_set.all()
        total = sum([item.quantity for item in order_items]) 
        return total

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return str(self.id)

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    @property
    def get_total(self):
        total = self.product.price * self.quantity
        return total  

class ShippingAdress(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null = True)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null = True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null = False)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.address
```

and the error message while trying to add a product:
[image]

The modelAdmin implementation:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import User, OTP
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin


class UserModelAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    # The fields to be used in displaying the User model.
    # These override the definitions on the base UserModelAdmin
    # that reference specific fields on auth.User.

    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password')}),
        ('Personal info', {'fields': ('name', 'is_analyst', 'DOB', 'gender', 'city_code')}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_active', 'is_admin', 'is_superuser', 'groups', 'user_permissions')}),
        ('Important dates', {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined')}),
    )
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('name', 'email', 'is_analyst', 'DOB', 'gender', 'city_code', 'password1', 'password2'),
        }),
    )
    list_display = ('email', 'name', 'is_active', 'is_admin', 'is_analyst')
    list_filter = ('is_active', 'is_admin', 'is_analyst')
    search_fields = ('email', 'name')
    ordering = ('email',)


# Now register the new UserModelAdmin...
admin.site.register(User, UserModelAdmin)
#admin.site.register(OTP)

@admin.register(OTP)
class OTPAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'user', 'code', 'has_used', 'task_type')
```

Comment: Can you share the modeladmin that is raisng the error?

Comment: Added the admin panel at the very end of the question. you meant that ?

Comment: @KhairAhmmad: no, you probably implement a subclass of `ModelAdmin` somewhere? Otherwise this will not show in the admin pages.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem got it, added at the end of the post.